# High latency between the azure web app and azure sql database

Tags: sql, database, azure, web-applications, latency

I create azure web app in west europe and azure sql database in west europe. When app connecting to sql database and execute simple select it takes 4 sec (even in local cheap hosting it takes 200-300ms). Its horrible. I create MySQL clear db and the same problem, horrible latency. The both services are in the same datacenter, why it takes so long time? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First what you can try is to scale your pricing plan on database server and App service. Besides, Azure has build in tool - Database Advisor, which can help you to fix your possible db issues (like add index). Finally - check out database metric (there is possibility to edit chart) to know for sure that this is network or db latency.

Comment: 1) application in dev stage and use 1-5% memory/cpu

2) requests very simple like select row from table with 5 rows

3) "always on" enabled

Comment: Ok, another thing what can change it is MultipleActiveResultSets. By default it's set to False in connection string on portal. If it is - set it to True

Comment: the same result

Comment: I don't think azure has a way to provide the managed sql service to be close enough to the web apps. My latency isn't nearly as bad as that but it is still around 50 - 70 ms which is still pretty horrid.It's a real shame because the got so close to fully managed maintream website hosting.